# Ubuntu 17.10 freeze after login on fresh install without USB

Tags: login, live-usb, 17.10, freeze, syslog

I decided to bring new life to a disused laptop by formatting and installing Ubuntu. I created a bootable USB stick using Rufus, and installed Ubuntu from it, formatting the hard drive in the process. The install went smoothly.
I then turned off the computer, removed the usb stick, and rebooted. Ubuntu starts and lets me log in, but just after I see the gnome desktop, everything freezes. The only way out is to do a hard reset.

I did the install again, leaving the usb stick in during reboot, and this time login went normally. Thinking the problem was solved, I ejected and removed the stick. After a reboot, the problem was back.

I've worked a while to resolve this, and consistently ubuntu freezes if the bootable USB is not plugged in during first login after rebooting. After login, the stick can be removed, and I can log out and in again without issue.

The freeze happends after I see the desktop, but I notice the trash icon dosn't appear. If the USB stick is in, the trash icon and the USB stick appear mounted on the desktop.

I've attached syslog, kern.log and auth.log after my last reinstall. They are quite short, as I installed, failed to log on, did a hard reset, logged on with stick and then copied the files. The crash happened at 14:13:47, notice the alternating \'s and 00's. The longer I wait before I hard reset, the longer this pattern in the logs appear.

I'm guessing there are some file on the USB stick that needs to be on the HD, but I have no idea which. If anyone can help with this I would be most grateful :)

Logs: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12lgRWasdXpbpT9RVoFqN84DNNeTE-_-5

Brg, Martin

EDIT:
Figured out that USB stick needs to be present during boot, not login. I can take it out on the login screen and it will still work.

Comment: I would suggest reinstalling at this point. Trying to isolate a singular system file, much less putting it in the exact right location is completely illogical, and way more work than is needed

Comment: I agree, but I've already tried several reinstalls at this point. I'll try to redownload and recreate the flash drive this time, maybe that'll help.

Comment: Did another reinstall, this time after formatting flash drive and installing ISO from ubuntu. Same issue. I'll try to install Ubuntu 16.04 tomorrow, see if that helps.

Comment: Ok, so 16.04 works. I tried to update via the software updater, and the same problem persisted, so I rolled back to 16.04 again. I guess i'll use that and hope the problem is fixed by the next LTS release.

Comment: My symptoms are similar but not identical, in that the presence or absence of the installer USB stick makes no difference: the mouse will stay responsive for a few seconds, then stutter to a stop within 1 second or less.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled over a solution while troubleshooting issues with freezing during suspend or shutdown - turns out that switching off an option related to USB 3.0 in BIOS solved both those problems and allowed me to install use Ubuntu 17.10 normally as well.

Comment: What was the option you switched off?

Comment: I switched off "xHCI support" in bios, described as an external USB3.0 controller. This was on an Acer aspire ES1-311. Hope it hels you, brg Martin.

Comment: Hm. I think it was switched off on my BIOS. I ended up working around my problem by installing Mint instead of Ubuntu.